# How to add else false to boolean method

Tags: java, selenium, testing, boolean, automated-tests

I have a boolean method that checks if certain elements are present.

It currently only returns true, but I want to assert it's false at a later stage of my testing when the elements are no longer displaying.

I'm using a webdriver wait to check the elements are present.

I've tried `isDisplayed()` and simple if and else statements but they won't work for me.

```
public boolean is_leaderbaord_viewable(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(position_header));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(player_header));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(num_of_players));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(leaderboard_picks_header));
    System.out.println("Leaderboard is now displayed");

    return true;
}
```

I just want to be able to assert it's either true or false in my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use try and catch:

```
try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(position_header));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(player_header));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(num_of_players));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(leaderboard_picks_header));
        System.out.println("Leaderboard is now displayed");

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: SHould i return true twice?

Comment: @FearghalQA sorry... `return false;`